# Synchronizing Analysis Services Tabular Model using SDK

Tags: powershell, sdk, synchronization, ssas, analysisservices

I am creating a Powershell script to allow synchronizing a tabular model between two servers.
I went through the documentation found for the Synchronize method on the [Analysis Services SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.core.server.synchronize?view=analysisservices-dotnet#Microsoft_AnalysisServices_Core_Server_Synchronize_System_String_System_String_)
and I really do not understand what should be given to the "source" parameter.
I have tried passing the server name/IP and an error is throw saying:

> The data source or location is not valid. Please provide a valid server to which to connect...

Had anyone used this method before? Could not find examples online.

Comment: Based on the description it sounds like you need to specify the source server from which to synchronize the local db. Probably `SourceServerName` or `SourceServerName\SourceDatabaseName`

Comment: Hi Mathias. 
I have tried with SourceServerName but it did not work. I also assume that we do not have to specify the database since the Sync should keep the same database name...

Something is wrong with that parameter.

Another weird behavior is that the documentation has methods with 4 parameters but when I tried to call it like that it said the method did not exist with 4 input parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the source argument for the Synchronize method is actually the connectionString to the source.